# Matlab, interp1

Tags: matlab

Hi I'm having some trouble getting two vectors to be the same size. Essentially I have one vector which contains a large number of elements and another vector that contains fewer elements which correspond to the elements in the larger vector.
e.g if my short vector had two elements these would correspond to the first and last elements in the larger vector, if three were in the small these would correspond to the first middle and last elements of the larger vector.
I need to generate interpolated values for the smaller vector so that it and the larger vector are the same size. I'm trying to use interp1 function but can't see a way to make it work.
Thanks

Simplified example, I hope this makes it clearer, the new C_L should still end with 0.0 and still start with 1.4, then the first lot of new numbers must be interpolated so that they are between 1.4 and 1.6, the next set between 1.6 and 1.7, and so on.

```
% For finding the lift curve slope across a wing
semispan = 8; % User inputs
C_L = [1.4,1.6,1.7,1.4,1.1,0.0]; % from a user input at stations which equally subdivide the wing.
x = 0:0.2:semispan

% C_L needs to be the same length as x
c_L = interp1(C_L,x,'linear','extrap') % Don't know how to do this part correctly.

plot(x,C_L)
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code. `but can't see a way to make it work` is vague... what is not working?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty explaining it, I added some code and comments that I hope will clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to make up a coordinate vector that gives the positions of the measurements given by the user and then use `interp1`.

For example, suppose you have three measurements, at points 0, 0.5, and 1--then the coordinate vector would be `[0, 0.5, 1]`.  It looks like your measurements are defined to be equally spaced between `0` and `semispan`, in which case you can make a vector of N equally spaced coordinates between (and including) those values using `linspace(0, semispan, N)`.

Once you have the coordinates of the measurements and the measurements themselves, you can then use `interp1` to interpolate the values between the actual measurements.

This should work:

```
% For finding the lift curve slope across a wing
semispan = 8; % User inputs
C_L = [1.4,1.6,1.7,1.4,1.1,0.0]; % from a user input at stations which equally subdivide the wing.
C_L_coord = linspace(0, semispan, length(C_L));

x = 0:0.2:semispan

% C_L needs to be the same length as x
C_L_interpolated = interp1(C_L_coord, C_L, x);

plot(C_L_coord, C_L, x, C_L_interpolated);
```